# What type of tool/statistic should I use to inspect two misaligned time series of different granularity?

Tags: time-series, correlation, descriptive-statistics, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have two separate time series, indexed by time in nanoseconds. They both measure the same thing but because they come about in two completely different ways, the number of observations they each give are not only irregularly spaced but are also different in number and don't align. Even the time is on different clocks so even the small subset of indices which match are not necessarily referring to exactly the same time.

When I just look at points for each every millisecond (anything from 0 to upwards of 30 observations in different millisecond buckets), match the values to timestamp, and plot all such coinciding observations the time series look identical (this is over 200,000 points). Yet cross correlating them gives very bad values, like `0.03` or `0.16`. And if I zoom in on these at sets of 20 or so consecutive points I begin to see all the misalignment generating this. I can look at zoomed out plots and actual values to ascertain myself that they are "generally speaking" measuring the same thing and hovering similary, but I'm not sure how to do this with time series tools or a proper statistic. If the index sets were of the same length then I would consider smoothing over less granular buckets, but because they are not, it's a bit harder to come up with something to translate "the zoomed out graphs look the same" into a number. What are some things I can do in this scenario?